# lambda expression reduces to x but how?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I must be missing a rule to beta reduction, because I don't understand the following reduction.

```
(\y.x) z
```

This reduces to x. Why?

```
(\x.x) z
```

This reduces to z. Why does the **above** expression reduce to x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce `(\y.x) z` you "replace every instance of the lambda'ed variable (y) with the expression you're evaluating it at (z)". There are no instances of `y` in `x`, so you just get `x`.

Note that I'm assuming there are no `y`s in `x`. If `x` is some expression that *does* contain `y` that reduction would be incorrect.